# How to generalize for variable m instead of using several conditional statement in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

This is the problem I am working on: http://rosalind.info/problems/fibd/

I am trying to generalize for variable `m` in the following code:

```
def fibonnaciMortalRabbit(n, m):

    #Set up list of of m different generation categories
    rabbits = [0 for x in range(m)]
    #Initate first rabbit pair
    rabbits[0] = 1

    #n - 1 to calculate right generation
    for i in range(n - 1):

        if m == 2:
            rabbits[0], rabbits[1] = rabbits[1], rabbits[0]
        elif m == 3:
            rabbits[0], rabbits[1], rabbits[2] = rabbits[1] + rabbits[2], rabbits[0], rabbits[1]
        elif m == 4:
            rabbits[0], rabbits[1], rabbits[2], rabbits[3] = rabbits[1] + rabbits[2] + rabbits[3], rabbits[0], rabbits[1], rabbits[2]
        elif m == 5:
            rabbits[0], rabbits[1], rabbits[2], rabbits[3], rabbits[4] = rabbits[1] + rabbits[2] + rabbits[3] + rabbits[4], rabbits[0], rabbits[1], rabbits[2], rabbits[3] 
    return sum(rabbits)


print(fibonnaciMortalRabbit(8, 2))
```

Is there any way to make a generalization for the conditional statements using variable `m` in the loop?

I am sure there's a better way to solve this problem, however what I've done so far works fine for the cases where I have a conditional statement for m.

The current problem I am working on state that `m < 20`, so I rather not write almost 20 different elif statement.

Comment: What is the general algorithm for mortal rabbits? Inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: Just for future reference, it would help if you explain, in *English,* what your intent is. That will make it a lot easier than having to decode what your actual code is trying to do :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I've added some more info now, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for based on the example conditions you have (however, I think you miss typed the one for `m == 5`):

```
for i in range(n - 1):
    tmp = sum(rabbits[1:])
    for j in range(m - 1):
        rabbits[j + 1] = rabbits[j]

    rabbits[0] = tmp
```

Comment: That's correct, I missed to give `rabbits[4]` any value for `m == 5`.
Thanks, I am going to see that works!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
from collections import deque

def fibonnaciMortalRabbit(n, m):
    rabbits = deque([0, 1, 1, 1], maxlen=m+1)

    for _ in range(2, n):
        rabbits.append(rabbits[-1] + rabbits[-2] - rabbits[0])
    return rabbits[-1]

In []:
fibonnaciMortalRabbit(6, 3)

Out[]
4

In []:
fibonnaciMortalRabbit(100, 20)

Out[]
353368918335207375428
```

Inspired by the answer in the comments:

```
def fibMR(n, m):
    rabbits = deque([0, 1], maxlen=m)

    for i in range(n-1):
        rabbits.append(sum(rabbits)-rabbits[-1])
    return sum(rabbits)

In []:
fibMR(6, 3)

Out[]:
4

In []:
fibMR(100, 20)

Out[]:
353368918335207375428
```

Just a comparison on timings:

```
%timeit fibonnaciMortalRabbit(1000, 20)
259 µs ± 8.17 µs per loop

%timeit fibMR(1000, 20)
1.13 ms ± 18.5 µs per loop
```

Just for comparison answer in the comments:

```
%timeit fib(1000, 20)
1.35 ms ± 17.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Didn't work. I solved it with my current solution and got access to others solutions like this: `def fib(n,k=1):
  ages = [1] + [0]*(k-1)
  for i in xrange(n-1):
    ages = [sum(ages[1:])] + ages[:-1]
  return sum(ages)`

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Interesting approach, and I get the same results from above - not sure why it doesn't work for you. It should be noted that all the list slicing would make it a bit slower (3X).